# Big-Oh, Concequence of a Definition

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have spent a lot of time reading questions and answers about Big-Oh on both here and math.stackexchange and seems that this is the best place for it as math.stackexchange don't seem to like questions of this sort. So I have been given some coursework at uni on my CS course and I don't fully understand it and was hoping you guys could help. I understand that "homework" questions are slightly frowned upon here so I have chosen another example that is **not** part of my coursework, but **is** of similar style.

**So here is the definition that I have been given in the notes:**
[image]

**And the question I have been given is:**

Using Definition 2.5 show that if f(n) is O(g(n)) then k + f(n) is also O(g(n)).

I have spent 3 days searching the web for any kind of answer to problems like these. Looking at definition 2.5 it says f(n) is O(g(n)) and k + f(n) is O(g(n)). That's enough for me, but it seems I have to prove how that is derived. I thought at first that it should be done somehow by induction but have since decided against that and there must be a simpler way.

Any help would be appreciated. I don't expect someone to just upright give me the answer. I would more prefer either a methodology or a reference to where I can learn the technique of doing this. Could I remind you again that this is **not** my actual coursework but a question of similar style.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose f(n) is O(g(n))
then there exists a c and a k' s.t. for all n > k':  f(n) <= cg(n)
now consider f(n) + k
let d be s.t k <= d*g(n)   for all n greater than k'
which you know is possible because k is in O(1)
then
f(n) + k <= cg(n) + dg(n) = (d+c)(g(n))
Then you use the definition and substitute d+c for c, ==> f+k is in O(g)

Comment: The question states that the given definition must be used.

Comment: This might be a silly question but what does s.t mean in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

f(n) <= cg(n)

k + f(n) <= c'g(n)
where c' = ck

so k + f(n) is O(g(n))

Answer (score 0):

Then `k` is `O(1)`, `f(n)` is a `O(g(n))` then you can sum this values then you have `O(1+g(n))` this is `O(g(n))`;

`f(n)` is `O(g(n))` then `k + f(n)` is also `O(g(n))`, because you have writed in your book

> Ignore addition of a constant

Constant are always ignored because can't change *Big-O* notation, any constant is `O(1)` in `Big-O` notation.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this is a somewhat contrived definition of big-O notation. The more general and, in my opinion, more intuitive definition is that `f(n) ~ O(g(n))` as `n->a` iff `lim|f(n)/g(n)| <= A` as `n->a` for some finite real number `A`.

The important part is that a limit context is required. In CS, that limit is taken implicitly to be infinity (since this is what `n` tends to as the problem size increases), but in principle it can be anything. For example, `sin(x) ~ O(x)` as `x->0` (in fact, it's exactly asymptotic to `x`; this is the small angle approximation).